# How can i use laravel 4 lock For Update

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, locking

Now i'm using Laravel 4 for website  development , when i'll edit record by this query

```
$cc=DB::table('customers')->where('transaction_id', '=', $_GET['edit'])->lockForUpdate()->get();
```

But when i login by another session  from another browser the user can show record as i do query on  page that select for update
Now i want every user lock record that edit it 
any help and thank you .

Comment: Ran into this question while searching for something else, and I have no idea what is being asked here.

Answer (score 0):

Lock for update will only work inside a transaction. Something like the following should work:

```
DB::transaction(function() {
    $cc = DB::table('customers')->where('transaction_id', '=', $_GET['edit'])->lockForUpdate()->get();
    ...
});
```